# How to update variable value using click and switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var varChange = '';
    var baseVar = 50;

    selectBaseVar = function(){
        switch (varChange) {case 101: varChange = 501; break;
                            case 501: varChange = 101; break;
                            default:  varChange = 101; break;}
        console.log('internal val: '+varChange);
        return varChange;
    };

    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        selectBaseVar();
    });

    selectBaseVar();

    console.log('external val: '+varChange);
    console.log('base baseVar = '+baseVar);
    baseVar += varChange;    // How do I update this value upon the button click event?
    console.log('updated baseVar = '+baseVar); // it works only in the document.ready state
});
```

Works for the `document.ready` state but not for the `click` event. A scope problem is maybe the cause.

I don't know how to workaround this issue

The intention is to left baseVar as constant @ 50

Increase the value of baseVar, due 

baseVar += varChange;

Switch varChange, and update baseVar

In docuent.ready state we got:

internal val: 101

external val: 101

base baseVar = 50

updated baseVar = 151

if I click, respectively I got internal values as expected:

internal val: 501

internal val: 101

But (updated baseVar = 151)  no matter what value it’s switching

And not what I’m up to, that is affecting the external variable **baseVar** with the values of:

updated baseVar = 151

updated baseVar = 551

note: there is a good reason to leave the **baseVar** variable out of the scope of the **selectBaseVar()** for the sake of other functions that benefit from the switch result of the same, but been out of the scope of **selectBaseVar()**.

Thanks

Comment: Where does this code live? Is this the body of your `$(document).ready` handler?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkqmm/1/

Make sure you're wrapping the code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you're trying to achieve is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var varChange, baseVar = 50;

    selectBaseVar = function(){
        varChange = (varChange == 101) ? 501 : 101;
        console.log('internal val: '+varChange);
        return varChange;
    };


    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        selectBaseVar();
        baseVar += varChange;
        console.log('button handler val: ' + varChange);
    });

    selectBaseVar();

    console.log('external val: ' + varChange);
    console.log('base baseVar = ' + baseVar);
    baseVar += varChange;    // How do I update this value upon the button click event?
    console.log('updated baseVar = ' + baseVar); // it works only in the document.ready state    
});
```